# Clients not receiving message in signalr

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr

my signalr connected clients are not receiving messages.
my chathub:

```
public class Chathub : Hub
    {
        private readonly string _botUser;
        private readonly string _globalRoom;
        public Chathub()
        {
            _botUser = "My Chatbot";
            _globalRoom = "Lobby";
        }
        public async Task Join(string message)
        {
            //await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, _globalRoom);
            //await Clients.Group(_globalRoom).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", $"{_botUser} : Welcome {message}");
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", $"{_botUser} : Welcome {Context.ConnectionId}"); //Checking connectionid
            //await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", $"{_botUser} : Welcome {message}");
        }
    }
```

I've defined my hubconnection in SharedService:

```
export class SharedService {

  public readonly URL = "https://localhost:44333/";
  private hubConnection: HubConnection;

  messageModel: Message = {
    message: null
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.BuildConnection();
    this.StartConnection();
    this.JoinMessage();
  }

  public BuildConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('/chathub').build();

  }

  public StartConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection.start()
      .then(() => console.log("Connection started...."))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  LoginUser(UserModel: User): Observable<User> {
    this.hubConnection.invoke("Join", UserModel.userName);
    return this.http.post<User>(this.URL + "Account/LoginUser", UserModel);
  }

  JoinMessage(): Observable<string> {
    this.hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", (messages) => {
      this.messageModel.message = messages;
    });
    return of(this.messageModel.message);
  }
```

I have two compenents. As soon as user logs in, hubconnection is started and is routed to another component which displays the welcome message.
Message is displayed like this

```
export class MainPageComponent implements OnInit {

  public messages = [];

  constructor(public service: SharedService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.DisplayMessage();
  }

  public DisplayMessage() {
    this.service.JoinMessage().subscribe((data) => this.messages.push(data));
  }
}
```

When I open two tabs and log in, The welcome message is not shared between this two tabs. The first loged in client is not receiving the message that welcomes the second client. I'm assuming the connectionId in chathub should be same for both clients to communicate with eachother however it's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return the correct Observable when subscribing (do not use `of()` here, use `Subject.next()` instead)

```
private message$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

 JoinMessage(): Observable<string> {
    this.hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", (messages) => {
      this.message$.next(messages);
    });
    return this.message$.asObservable();
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Alexey. This partly works but there are some problems.
Firstly, The user do not get messages as soon as he logs in. like WElcome user 1
Secondly, The first logged in User receives two welcome message when User 2 logs in. like Welcome user 2 twice.

Comment: @ShanksLimbu the first problem is related to the fact that the user subscribes to Subject after the message is received by hub, it can be fixed by using `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject` with buffer size 1 instead of `Subject` (see docs for more details). The second issue is appearing since it seems you call `JonMessage` twice, it must be called only once per user

Comment: @icekson Could you please take a look at this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776033/signalr-the-new-message-does-not-shows-in-target-clients-message-box-angular